# Can Not Access Static Class Function?

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

Here is my Code

```
static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}
class manageCAN
{
    // Getting the String for .dll Address
    string dllfile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\VTC1010_CAN_Bus.dll";
    // Loading dll using Native Methods
    IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllfile);
}
```

I get an error: Error   1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'manageDLL.manageCAN.dllfile'

Please suggest a solution. Why can't I initialize my variable "pDll"?

Comment: Put the `dllfile` and `pDll` initializations (both, for consistency and readability) in your `manageCAN` constructor. See duplicate for why.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to learn about .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I initialize my variable "pDll"?

The compiler is telling you exactly why - you can't access instance fields within an instance field initializer. It looks like these should probably be static anyway:

```
static readonly string dllfile = ...;
static readonly IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllfile);
```

But if you *really* want them to be instance fields, you'll need to initialize `pDll` in the constructor:

```
class manageCAN
{
    // Getting the String for .dll Address
    string dllfile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\VTC1010_CAN_Bus.dll";
    // Loading dll using Native Methods
    IntPtr pDll;

    public manageCAN()
    {
        pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet, I like the way you answered the question without taking jibe at the at my apparent lack of knowledge about .Net development. After reading your post i got what a stupid mistake I was making. I shouldn't have asked this question. Answer was already there as you mentioned (I just had a Eureka moment)